# GLKView frame size animation causes GL to render only a portion of the screen

Tags: ios, animation, opengl-es, glkit

I have a GLKView contained in a UIView under a top, nav-like bar.  The bar can be shown/hidden  with an animation and the autolayout pinning causes the views to fill the portion of the screen under the bar (or the full screen if hidden).

What's odd is that when the top bar begins its show/hide animation, the GLKView immediately jumps to the final height.  When showing the top bar (which shrinks the GLKView), it causes clear band to be seen on the top and bottom.

What's also odd is that the view's position seems to work correctly, and animates smoothly down as the top bar comes down until they all eventually line up as they should.

Dumping out out the GLKView's layer.presentationLayer property seems to indicate that it's bounds animates correctly.

The GLK-ness of the view could be a red-herring as I haven't tested this on other parts of the app...will do though...

Very confused.  Sorry no photos but it's all NDA and I've no time to make a sample project right now.  Maybe later if need be.  Thanks...

Comment: Did you solve it?